# Python classes, mappings, pprint, KeysView vs. dict_keys; to keys() or not to keys()?

Tags: python, class, types, mapping

I have a problem with my base class. I started writing it after finding an answer on this site about more informative `__repr__()` methods. I added to it after finding a different answer on this site about using `pprint()` with my own classes. I tinkered with it a little more after finding a third answer on this site about making my classes unpackable with a `**` operator.

I modified it again after seeing in yet another answer on this site that there was a distinction between merely giving it `__getitem__()`, `__iter__()`, and `__len__()` methods on the one hand, and actually making it a fully-qualified mapping by subclassing `collections.abc.Mapping` on the other. Further, I saw that doing so would remove the need for writing my own `keys()` method, as the `Mapping` would take care of that.

So I got rid of `keys()`, and a class method broke.

### The problem

I have a method that iterates through my class' keys and values to produce one big string formatted as I'd like it. That class looks like this.

```py
class MyObj():
    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar

    def the_problem_method(self):
        """Method I'm getting divergent output for."""
        longest = len(max((key for key in self.keys()), key=len))
        key_width = longest + TAB_WIDTH - longest % TAB_WIDTH
        return '\n'.join((f'{key:<{key_width}}{value}' for key, value in self))
```

Yes, that doesn't have the base class in it, but the MWE later on will account for that. The nut of it is that `(key for key in self.keys())` part. When I have a `keys()` method written, I get the output I want.

```py
    def keys(self):
        """Get object attribute names."""
        return self.__dict__.keys()
```

When I remove that to go with the `keys()` method supplied by `collections.abc.Mapping`, I get no space between `key` and `value`

### The question

I can get the output I want by restoring the `keys()` method (and maybe adding `values()` and `items()` while I'm at it), but is that the best approach? Would it be better to go with the `Mapping` one and modify my class method to suit it? If so, how? Should I leave `Mapping` well enough alone until I know I need it?

This is my base class to be copied all aver creation and subclassed out the wazoo. I want to Get. It. Right.

There are already several considerations I can think of and many more of which I am wholly ignorant.

1. I use Python 3.9 and greater. I'll abandon 3.9 when `conda` does.
2. I want to keep my more-informative `__repr__()` methods.
3. I want `pprint()` to work, via the `_dispatch` table method with `_format_dict_items()`.
4. I want to allow for duck typing my classes reliably.
5. I have not yet used type hinting, but I want to allow for using best practices there if I start.
6. Everything else I know nothing about.

### The MWE

This has my problem class at the top and output stuff at the bottom. There are two series of classes building upon the previous ones.

The first are ever-more-inclusive base classes, and it is here that the difference between the instance with the `keys()` method and that without is shown. the class, `BaseMap`, subclasses the `Mapping` and has the `__getitem__()`, `__iter__()`, and `__len__()` methods. The next class up the chain, `BaseMapKeys`, subclasses that and adds the `keys()` method.

The second group, `MapObj` and `MapKeysObj`, are subclasses of the problem class that also subclass those different base classes respectively.

OK, maybe the WE isn't so M, but lots of things got me to this point and I don't want to neglect any.

```py
import collections.abc
from pprint import pprint, PrettyPrinter


TAB_WIDTH = 3


class MyObj():
    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar

    def the_problem_method(self):
        """Method I'm getting divergent output for."""
        longest = len(max((key for key in self.keys()), key=len))
        key_width = longest + TAB_WIDTH - longest % TAB_WIDTH
        return '\n'.join((f'{key:<{key_width}}{value}' for key, value in self))


class Base(object):
    """Base class with more informative __repr__."""

    def __repr__(self):
        """Object representation."""
        params = (f'{key}={repr(value)}'
                  for key, value in self.__dict__.items())
        return f'{repr(self.__class__)}({", ".join(params)})'


class BaseMap(Base, collections.abc.Mapping):
    """Enable class to be pprint-able, unpacked with **."""

    def __getitem__(self, attr):
        """Get object attribute values."""
        return getattr(self.__dict__, attr)

    def __iter__(self):
        """Make object iterable."""
        for attr in self.__dict__.keys():
            yield attr, getattr(self, attr)

    def __len__(self):
        """Get length of object."""
        return len(self.__dict__)


class BaseMapKeys(BaseMap):
    """Overwrite KeysView output with what I thought it would be."""

    def keys(self):
        """Get object attribute names."""
        return self.__dict__.keys()


class MapObj(BaseMap, MyObj):
    """Problem class with collections.abc.Mapping."""

    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        super().__init__(foo, bar)


class MapKeysObj(BaseMapKeys, MyObj):
    """Problem class with collections.abc.Mapping and keys method."""

    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        super().__init__(foo, bar)


if isinstance(getattr(PrettyPrinter, '_dispatch'), dict):
    # assume the dispatch table method still works
    def pprint_basemap(printer, object, stream, indent, allowance, context,
                       level):
        """Implement pprint for subclasses of BaseMap class."""
        write = stream.write
        write(f'{object.__class__}(\n {indent * " "}')
        printer._format_dict_items(object, stream, indent, allowance + 1,
                                   context, level)
        write(f'\n{indent * " "})')
    map_classes = [MapObj, MapKeysObj]
    for map_class in map_classes:
        PrettyPrinter._dispatch[map_class.__repr__] = pprint_basemap


def print_stuff(map_obj):
    print('pprint object:')
    pprint(map_obj)
    print()
    print('print keys():')
    print(map_obj.keys())
    print()
    print('print list(keys()):')
    print(list(map_obj.keys()))
    print()
    print('print the problem method:')
    print(map_obj.the_problem_method())
    print('\n\n')


params = ['This is a really long line to force new line in pprint output', 2]
baz = MapObj(*params)
print_stuff(baz)
scoggs = MapKeysObj(*params)
print_stuff(scoggs)
```

Comment: As an aside, `max((key for key in self.keys()), key=len)` should just be `max(self.keys(), key=len)`, in general, `(x for x in whatever)` should just be `whatever`

Comment: But, I'm not following, `MyObj` doesn't *have* a `.keys` attribute, so why is it using it in `the_problem_method`?

Comment: So, in general for a mapping, it's `__iter__` should iterate over the *keys*, whereas your `__iter__` is iterating over key-value pairs...

Comment: And as a corollary to that, `for attr in self.__dict__.keys()` should just be `for attr in self.__dict__: ...`

Comment: But anyway, there is a lot going on here, and you haven't really succinctly described the exact problem, but my guess is that it is your implementation of `__iter__`, which could really just be `return iter(self.__dict__)`

Comment: ALSO, your `__getitem__` is broken in `BaseMap`, `getattr(self.__dict__, attr)` should be `self.__dict__[attr]` (preferred IMO) or `getattr(self, attr)` (but then you need to be careful to raise a KeyError instead of an AttributeError). So fix these two methods and maybe your problem gets resolved, but they should definitely get fixed regardless

Comment: I've incorporated some of your suggestions, and thanks. The `keys()` method is absent from one base class and present in another, as I've added above. I could not get your change to `__iter__()` to work, however. `pprint()` seems to need it the way I had it. Taking out my `_format_dict_items` bit didn't help. Taking `pprint()` out entirely moved the runtime errors to the problem function.

Comment: I can only guess that's because it is expecting the `.items()` from your mapping, not the mapping itself, which is what you are passing to it. Hard to say, since you are not working with any documented API AFAIKT, so these are all private implementation details. Regardless, `__iter__` should **definitely not** return key-value pairs

Comment: So yeah, that's exactly how that method is used in the source code: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/pprint.py#L206

Comment: What runtime errors in the problem function?

Comment: It's because you are doing `return '\n'.join((f'{key:<{key_width}}{value}' for key, value in self))`. Again, mapping types **should not iterate over key-value pairs**. So just do what you are doing in `__iter__` in there... it could literally just be `for key,value in vars(self).items()`

Comment: OK, yes: changing `__iter__()` as you said and changing `key...value for key, value` to `key...self[key] for key` fixes my main problem, and my function gives the right output both times. I guess I'd been working so long with `dict.items()` that I patterned on that and stuck it where it shouldn't go. Thank you for helping me sort that out. Now I have to fix how I'm trying to use `pprint()` in light of that.

Comment: And, I fixed the `pprint()` issue. Where I had been using `_format_dict_items` with the old, bad `__iter__()`, using `_format_items` with your `__iter__()` clears up that issue. Thanks again.